# Optimal .NET method for transfering large files in client-server application with ability to pause and resume

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webclient, file-transfer

I am writing a .NET WINFORMS client-server application where the client will need to be able to transfer large files onto the client that are hosted by the server.  I am writing both ends of the software so I have complete control over how to do the transfer, but I don't know what the best .NET approach is.

The server will be serving up files from it's hard drive and it will know the file size. The server will only serve up one file at a time and only to one user at a time. The client will need to display the speed and progress of the transfer. It will also need the ability to pause and resume the transfer. I also want to be able to pause and resume across sessions - for example I pause and close the client, and when I reopen the client I can resume the transfer.

My plan was to use the .NET `WebClient` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx)) class but I don't know if there are better ways to do this. I know I'm not the first person with these requirements so I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Any suggestions?

Comment: the hTTP protocol has a lot of the functionality built-in (resume methods). Progress is just a matter of testing `readBytes / totalbytes * 100`. You could use WCF, but you'd have to implement the pause/resume yourself. Chances are you're looking at a thread-safe wrapper class that you can poll periodically from the UI to check progress, but in the background is working to send/receive files.

Comment: Are you uploading to a web server? That's the only reason for using WebClient (or better yet, HttpClient). In a local network there are a myriad ways of transfering/replicating/synchronizing files.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm not doing anything to a web server. I have a local network with a PC running my server winforms app and a PC running my client winforms app. I know there are a myriad of ways to do it, but I'm asking for specifics. And in particular, what is recommended.

Comment: What's your scenario then? You describe a possible UI but not the actual problem. Replication can be handled by DFS and other mechanisms, local file shares can sync to a server etc. Do you want to sync changes or entire files? This has little to do with .NET

Comment: The server has a file. The client wants it. The client connects to the server and downloads the file from the server. I'm not concerned with UI. I'm concerned with what .NET class should I use to do this transfer.